# Magento image CDN Amazon s3 images half work half dont

Tags: image, magento, amazon-s3, cdn

I am using Magento 1.11.  I have been searching for a while now and I have tried a bunch of different things such as increasing the memory size in my php.ini page, which helped with some of the images that are in my media directory.  However, half of the ones that reference the Amazon CDN are not working, the other half are.  This is what led me to believe it was a memory issue.  Also, this is a dev environment ment to represent the existing produciton environment.  All of the images on the production environment are working.

I am at a loss.

thank you for any suggestions.